# Event Delegates using IIFE or Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am learning jQuery/JavaScript best practices and am attempting to put them into practice. My overall goal is to have lots of small, independent .js files which contain specific functionality and will not intrude or collide with other files, then concat/minify them for production as one file; basing some concepts off of [John Papa's AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

I'm trying to understand IIFEs and jQuery delegate event handling. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but my attempt here is to isolate a specific event handler in its own contained block. If an IIFE is used, does this event remain registered/delegated to the span or does the IFFE invoke once and the event is no longer registered?

I'm not worried about the code working but more concerned with learning how to structure jQuery Event Delegates in a modular way using the example below.

```
(function(window, document, $){
   var $icon = $('.icon');

   $icon.on('click', 'span', function() {
      var me = this;
      me.toggleClass('open');
   });   

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, the event stays registered.

Comment: @Gary Storey Great, thank you! And is this a common practice, i.e. putting blocks of code into separate self-contained files in their own anonymous IIFE's?

Comment: I do it all the time.  Then I use a build tool, gulp in my case, to lint and the concatenate the files.

Comment: Also, you should make sure to add `'use strict';` immediately inside the IIFE to put your code into JS strict mode.

Comment: @GaryStorey yep added `'use strict';` to the IIFE. I was also going to look at concatenation and minification of my JS files too. I'll look at some tools and see what works for me. Thanks!